# There is no Action mapped for action name elecMenuAction_menuHome

Tags: java, jsp, struts, struts-config

> Struts Problem Report
>
> Struts has detected an unhandled exception:
>
> Messages:
>   There is no Action mapped for action name elecMenuAction_menuHome.
>
> Stacktraces
>
> There is no Action mapped for action name elecMenuAction_menuHome. - [unknown location]
>
> com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionProxy.prepare(DefaultActionProxy.java:185)
>   org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxy.prepare(StrutsActionProxy.java:63)
>   org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxyFactory.createActionProxy(StrutsActionProxyFactory.java:39)
>   com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionProxyFactory.createActionProxy(DefaultActionProxyFactory.java:58)
>   org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:500)
>   org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.ExecuteOperations.executeAction(ExecuteOperations.java:77)
>   org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.doFilter(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:91)
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:218)
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:110)
>   org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:506)
>
> ...

My `struts.xml`:

```
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
    "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.3//EN"
    "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.3.dtd">
<struts>
    <!-- dev model -->
    <constant name="struts.devMode" value="true"></constant>
    <!-- ui  -->
    <constant name="struts.ui.theme" value="simple"></constant>
    <!-- .do-->
    <constant name="struts.action.extension" value="do"></constant>

    <!-- system management -->
    <package name="system" namespace="/system" extends="struts-default">
        <!-- test -->
        <action name="elecTextAction_*" class="elecTextAction" method="{1}">
            <result name="save">/system/textAdd.jsp</result>
        </action>

        <action name="elecMenuAction_*" class="elecMenuAction" method="{1}">
            <result name="menuHome">/WEB-INF/page/menu/home.jsp</result>
        </action>  // I add this action then report error.
    </package>
</struts>
```

In my `ElecMenuAction.java`:

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
@Controller("elecMenuAction")
@Scope(value = "prototype")
public class ElecMenuAction extends BaseAction<MenuForm> {

    MenuForm menuForm = this.getModel();

    public String menuHome(MenuForm menuForm) {

        return "menuHome";
    }

}
```

In my `menu/index.jsp`:

```
<form action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/menu/elecMenuAction_menuHome.do" method="post" target="_top">
```

My directory is below:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

Comment: Did you try tweaking the mapping settings without the special character '*'

Comment: @ShivamAggarwal I test, but no use.

Answer (score 0):

I saw your package config in `struts.xml` is this:

```
<package name="system" namespace="/system" extends="struts-default">
```

But your form action is like this below, why is `menu` but `system`:

```
<form action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/menu/elecMenuAction_menuHome.do" method="post" target="_top">
```

You should change the `action` to :

```
action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/system/elecMenuAction_menuHome.do"
```

That's why Action mapped can not find reason.